# Python: Generate a geometric progression using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

In Python, Can I generate a geometric progression using list comprehensions alone? I don't get how to refer to elements that were added to the list.

That would be like [Writing python code to calculate a Geometric progression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800804/writing-python-code-to-calculate-a-geometric-progression) or [Generate list - geometric progression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225617/generate-list-geometric-progression).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

List comprehensions don't let you refer to previous values. You could get around this by using a [more appropriate tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import mul
length = 10
ratio = 2
progression = list(accumulate([ratio]*length, mul))
```

or by avoiding the use of previous values:

```
progression = [start * ratio**i for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 5):

If a geometric progression is defined by `a_n = a * r ** (n - 1)` and `a_n = r * a_(n - 1)`, then you could just do the following:

```
a = 2
r = 5
length = 10

geometric = [a * r ** (n - 1) for n in range(1, length + 1)]

print(geometric)
# [2, 10, 50, 250, 1250, 6250, 31250, 156250, 781250, 3906250]
```